# Setting end date time (hour and minutes) after start date time

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have 2 date objects - start date and end date. I have a requirement where my end date's time should be an hour after the time of start date i.e. let's say start date is Feb 12, 3:00 pm and my end date is Feb 15th, but display time for my end date should be 4:00pm i.e. an hour after the start time.

***Here is what I tried:***

```
let startDateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: startDateTime)
print("startDateComponents - \(startDateComponents)")
                
endDateTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: startDateTime) ?? endDateTime
```

This works fine when I have both the dates same i.e. Start date is Feb 12th and end date is also Feb 12th, then I get start date as Feb 12, 3:00pm and end date as Feb 12, 4:00pm. However if my end date is Feb 15 and I am expecting end date to Feb 15th, 4:00pm, running the above code gives me Feb 12th, 4:00pm.

How can I create a date object with just change in time?

Also if start date if Feb 12, 11:00pm, when I change the time on end date, it should turn into next date i.e. Feb 16th 00:00am and not Feb 15th 00:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach using `DateComponents` from the `startDate` and the `endDate`
to construct your `newEndDate` having the same hours, minutes, seconds
as the `startDate`.

Example code:

```
let startDate = Date()
let endDate = Date().addingTimeInterval(60*60*24*3 + 125)
print("--->  startDate: \(startDate)   endDate: \(endDate)")

let startComp = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: startDate)
var endComp = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: endDate)

let addition = 1 // hour

endComp.hour = (startComp.hour ?? 0) + addition    // <--- here
endComp.minute = startComp.minute // <--- here
endComp.second = startComp.second // <--- here

let newEndDate = Calendar.current.date(from: endComp) ?? endDate
print("---> newEndDate: \(newEndDate)")
```

Gives:

--->  startDate: 2024-02-13 00:27:18 +0000   endDate: 2024-02-16 00:29:23 +0000
---> newEndDate: 2024-02-16 01:27:18 +0000

Comment: What's "+125" for while creating endDate on line 2?

Comment: it's just to add some number of seconds to the date, nothing more than that. You can remove it, the code will work just the same. Does the answer give you what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've submitted above appears to be working for me. Can you provide more details as to the context of your code?

```swift
import Foundation

var startDateTime = Date.now
let startDateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: startDateTime)
print("startDateComponents - \(startDateComponents)")

var endDateTime = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 8, to: startDateTime)
```

when ran in a playground gave me the current date
`"12 Feb 2024 at 4:31 PM"`
and an endDateTime of
`"13 Feb 2024 at 12:31 AM"`.

> Also if start date if Feb 12, 11:00pm, when I change the time on end date, it should turn into next date i.e. Feb 16th 00:00am and not Feb 15th 00:00.

I'm not 100% sure if that's what you're asking, but as far as a bidirectional relationship between start and end date, I would probably implement this with an object along these lines, but you'll need to adjust based on your own use case.

```swift
struct RelatedDateInterval {
    private var _startDateTime: Date
    var startDateTime: Date {
        get {
            return _startDateTime
        }
        
        set {
            _startDateTime = newValue
            if timeInterval != endDateTime.timeIntervalSince(newValue) {
                _endDateTime = newValue.addingTimeInterval(timeInterval)
            }
        }
    }
    private var _endDateTime: Date
    var endDateTime: Date {
        get {
            return _endDateTime
        }
        
        set {
            _endDateTime = newValue
            if timeInterval != newValue.timeIntervalSince(_startDateTime) {
                _startDateTime = newValue.addingTimeInterval(-timeInterval)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private let timeInterval: TimeInterval
    
    init(startDateTime: Date, endDateTime: Date) {
        self.timeInterval = endDateTime.timeIntervalSince(startDateTime)
        self._startDateTime = startDateTime
        self._endDateTime = endDateTime
    }
}

var relatedDateInterval = RelatedDateInterval(startDateTime: startDateTime, endDateTime: endDateTime)
print("Old dates - \(relatedDateInterval.startDateTime) - \(relatedDateInterval.endDateTime)")
relatedDateInterval.startDateTime = Date.distantFuture
print("New dates - \(relatedDateInterval.startDateTime) - \(relatedDateInterval.endDateTime)")
```

returns `"Old dates - 2024-02-12 23:42:23 +0000 - 2024-02-13 07:42:23 +0000\n"` and `"New dates - 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 - 4001-01-01 08:00:00 +0000\n"`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! My code was working as long as both start and end date are the same. If they are different, then executing the code was setting end date as the start date. I didn't wanted to set end date as my start date, I just wanted time of start date and add an hour to it and set that time for end date.